# Can't export data_bag items using chef in kitchen

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

The error occurs while trying to converge node.

```
     NoMethodError
     -------------
     undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
     
     Cookbook Trace:
     ---------------
       /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/system/recipes/filebeat.rb:30:in `block in from_file'
       /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/system/recipes/filebeat.rb:24:in `from_file'
       /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/system/recipes/default.rb:88:in `from_file'
       /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/role-base/recipes/default.rb:1:in `from_file'
     
     Relevant File Content:
     ----------------------
     /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/system/recipes/filebeat.rb:
     
      23:  # Lay down newrelic-infra agent config
      24:  template '/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml' do
      25:    source 'filebeat/filebeat.yml.erb'
      26:    owner 'root'
      27:    group 'root'
      28:    mode '00600'
      29:    variables(
      30>>     'cloud_id' => elastic_credentials[node.chef_environment]['cloud_id'],
      31:      'cloud_auth' => elastic_credentials[node.chef_environment]['cloud_auth']
      32:    )
      33:    notifies :restart, 'service[filebeat]', :delayed
      34:  end
```

Provisioner settings:

```
    provisioner:
       product_name: chef
       environments_path: ./test/integration/environments/
       data_bags_path: ./test/integration/data_bags/
       product_version: 13
```

JSON data_bag file:

```
   {
   "id": "elastic",
   "production" : {
     "cloud_id": "test",
     "cloud_auth": "test"
     }
   }
```

Issue isn't reproduced if kitchen uses chef_zero, however I need chef version versatility, so problem is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Your `node.chef_environment` is obviously something other than "production". Therefore `elastic_credentials[node.chef_environment]` returns `nil`, and you cannot call `[]` on `nil`.

If you need to debug the values of the variables, like `elastic_credentials`. You can login into your node, find the chef cache folder for the cookbooks (often `/etc/chef/cache/cookbooks/`) and add some `pp elastic_credentials` here and there.

After that run `chef-client --skip-cookbook-sync` and chef will run without downloading cookbooks from Chef Server, but solely on cache and you will see your values printed in console.